# WCF error when using POST over SSL/HTTPS

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ssl, iis

I'm having troubles with a WCF service. Service is hosted on IIS, client is a Windows Forms application. When invoked by WinForms, service gives a 404 error in an InnerException.

On IIS log I have the following:

```
2016-04-11 11:26:38 192.168.0.202 POST /services/statsservice.asmx - 443 - 192.168.0.37 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+4.0.30319.42000) - 200 0 0 613
2016-04-11 11:26:41 192.168.0.202 GET /support/versioninfo.aspx action=CheckUserVersion&UserVersion=2016.1.0.0 80 - 192.168.0.37 - - 200 0 0 109
2016-04-11 11:26:41 192.168.0.202 GET /support/versioninfo.aspx action=GetCurrentVersionNumber&Channel=stable 80 - 192.168.0.37 - - 200 0 0 86
2016-04-11 11:26:46 192.168.0.202 GET /Services/AskForSupportWCF.svc wsdl 443 - 192.168.0.37 - - 200 0 0 58
2016-04-11 11:26:53 192.168.0.202 POST /Services/AskForSupportWCF.svc wsdl 443 - 192.168.0.37 - - 404 0 0 15
```

As you can see, the client makes some calls to various pages and services. Error occurs during lates, a POST to a WCF service. As far as I can tell this is not an IIS misconfiguration, since previous POST to an .asmx page is successful. Is there any way to enable a WCF webservice to accept POST explicitly? Is it disabled by default or what?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check if you are able to browse AskForSupportWCF.svc url over https and load metadata i.e. wsdl?

Comment: I'm not the OP but the second to last line in the log shows a GET on the same URL and same port resulting in a 200 (OK), so that seems to work.

Comment: Yes @PankajKapare, I can successfully browse the service with a browser but that's still a GET request

Comment: Oh wait, same URL in log - you are apparently POSTing to /Services/AskForSupportWCF.svc?wsdl ... drop the ?wsdl query parameter!